# Ionic4 get data inside an object which is inside an object with ngFor

Tags: angular, object, ionic4, ngfor

Im trying to show some data from Api, but the data I need is inside an object which is inside an object. how do I get it?

Im trying to get `full_url` inside data object, which is inside avatar object. I already tried:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users.data">
        <ion-label>
            <h2>{{ user.uname }}</h2>
            <p *ngFor="let data of user.avatar.data">{{ data.url }}</p>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here's the Api Response Structure:
[Api Response Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/134R0.png)

Response I got is:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.avatar.data` is an object, not array. Therefore you are getting this error.

Either modify the response to pass an array, or simple change the `<p>` tag like:

```
<p>{{ user.avatar.data.url }}</p>
```